# How to install Gnatcoll Postgres on Linux Centos 7

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos7, ada, gnat

I have installed gprbuild, xmlada, and gnatcoll. I am now attempting to install gnatcoll_postgres. Which I have downladed from here: https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-db/

Within the Postgres folder is a Makefile, which I execute like so...

```
[parallels@localhost postgres]$ ls
gnatcoll_postgres.gpr              gnatcoll-sql-postgres-gnade.ads
gnatcoll-sql-postgres.adb          gnatcoll-sql-ranges.adb
gnatcoll-sql-postgres.ads          gnatcoll-sql-ranges.ads
gnatcoll-sql-postgres-builder.adb  Makefile
gnatcoll-sql-postgres-builder.ads  postgres_support.c
gnatcoll-sql-postgres-gnade.adb    README.md
[parallels@localhost postgres]$ make Makefile
which: no gnatls in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/parallels/.local/bin:/home/parallels/bin)
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile'.
[parallels@localhost postgres]$
```

Would anybody please be able to tell me what this means...

```
which: no gnatls in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/parallels/.local/bin:/home/parallels/bin)
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Please see the xmlada and gnatcoll in my project below, does this look like it's installed correctly? I'm presuming this isn't correct...

[image: GNAT GPS COMMUNITY]

Thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: ... how did you install Gnat? message suggests you didn't.

Comment: HI @BrianDrummond - I downloaded and installed GNAT Comunity, but I didn't use the terminal... It's installed here: /home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin/gps

Comment: As noted in my answer, you don’t need to build Gnatcoll or Xmlada since they are included in the Community package. Even if you did, I don’t see why you would have Xmlada on its own and also inside Gnatcoll

Answer (score 3):

It means that your GNAT installation binaries aren’t on your PATH.

The README.txt from the adacore.com site says, in part,

> To start using the tools in command-line mode, you will need to add
>
> `{install_prefix}/bin`
>
> to your PATH environment variable. Alternatively, you can simply launch
>
> `{install_prefix}/bin/gps`
>
> and GPS will automatically add itself to the PATH - it will also find the
>   cross compiler, if you have installed everything in the default locations.
>   Note that GPS will add this at the *end* of the PATH, meaning that it will find first any other GNAT installations that you have in your PATH.

---

I strongly suspect that you’ve been doing the latter, so that GPS adds itself (actually, of course, its own location) to the PATH, so that when it launches the compiler it finds the correct one.

When you run `make` from the terminal, the compiler isn’t on the PATH, so neither are `gnatls`, `gprconfig`, `gprbuild` and the rest of the GNAT tools.

What you need to do is to take the first choice from the README, and add `/home/parallel/opt/GNAT/2019/bin` to (the front of) your default PATH. How you do that depends on your shell.

You will find `xmlada`, `gnatcoll` already installed.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering @SimonWright - I  previously installed GPS here: /home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin/gps    -     Is this what I need to add to the Makefile prefix? Something like... prefix := $ /home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin/gps

Comment: I have now included a picture with the question, which shows how my project looks?

Comment: Thank you for the awnser! Do you know if it would be possible to build the the projects within https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-db/ i.e. sql and postgres within GNAT GPS, instead of using the Terminal?

Comment: Hi @Simon Wright, when you said "What you need to do is to take the first choice from the README, and add /home/parallel/opt/GNAT/2019/bin to (the front of) your default PATH. How you do that depends on your shell." Is that within the Make file, that I need to do this?

Comment: No it is not within the Makefile; you need to alter the PATH in your terminal (i.e. in your shell). See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/812243) for a suggestion as to how to do this.